# Different invariant tori in the case of a 2D harmonic oscillator

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, hamilton-equations

Both textbooks I'm currently reading (*Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* by Arnol'd - get it [here](https://loshijosdelagrange.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/v-arnold-mathematical-methods-of-classical-mechanics-1989.pdf) - and *Classical Mechanic*s by Shapiro - [here](https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/%7Eshapiro/507/gettext.shtml)) say that, in the case of the planar harmonic oscillator, using polar or cartesian coordinate systems leads to different action-angle variables (and I'm ok with that) and *different* invariant tori.

I think I've understood *in what sense* those tori could be different (i.e. not diffeomorphic at all), but I'd be very glad to see a proof (or even read an insight)

Comment: You're asking for a *demonstration*?

Comment: Thank you @DavidG.Stork for pointing out the quid pro quo, I've edited the question